# Field content from other site in hint on a site

Tags: google-chrome, browser, javascript, cookies, local-storage

Today on some site when I've clicked into guest name field on some site, I saw my full name as been written in state declarations and official documents and never was given on the site, yet I come the site time-to-time.
Not a multiple choice to choose like usual, just two variants, both official.

I suppose, it was taken from browser cookies, localStorage or sessionStorage by designated field name.
The cookies seem to be least relevant because of direct breach.

The field look very innocent.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="35" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
```

The browser is portable and a bit outdated.
*(The browser name was
Google Chrome - An error occurred while checking for updates: Update check failed to start (error code 1: 0x80004005).
Learn more
Version 89.0.4389.90 (Official Build) (32-bit)
)*

Yes, I do know and do suggest everybody have only the latest versions of programs and always update.

But - what is the way?

Is it can be available like so for a script on any site?

Comment: Some plugins like LastPass and even Chrome itself can locally store this info if you fill it in. If you have a form and it has matching properties, such as Name, it can fill this info in for you to save you time.

Comment: OP, check what you have in chrome:settings/addresses

Comment: @Matti Nescio, chrome:settings/addresses is empty.